# Replace forward slash with jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

This is my string:

```
hello/page/2/bye
```

This is what I would have (please note that "2" could be any number, "page" is always "page":

```
hello/bye
```

How can I do with str.replace() using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it (without jQuery):

```
var str = 'hello/page/2/bye';
str = str.replace(/page\/\d+\//,'');
```

The slashes need to be escaped (so they become `\/`), `\d+` is any number, one or more times (so it also matches e.g. `page/12/`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dd5aohbc/